# Is it possible to prevent the headless Chrome window get up when running it?

Tags: python, selenium, headless

On my Mac, I use the below selenium code to search the Python keyword in headless Chrome.

```
from selenium import webdriver

wd = webdriver.Chrome(r"/opt/webdrivers/chromedriver")

wd.implicitly_wait(5)

wd.get("https://www.google.com")


element = wd.find_element_by_id('kw')
element.send_keys('Python\n')

element = wd.find_element_by_class_name('c-abstract')

print(element.text)
```

but, however, the Chrome will open up a window automatically.

[image]

my understanding of headless browser will now open a window. In spite of this, is it possible to restrain the GUI get up, let it run in silence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about `headless chrome` but you can run chrome with headless mode by following options

```py
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')
options.add_argument("disable-gpu")

wd = webdriver.Chrome(r"/opt/webdrivers/chromedriver")
```